# Stateful widget consumer widget builds twice and hence calls initState twice. How to stop this from happening?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, stateful, rebuild

So for my project, I am using Riverpod, and I am creating the home page of my app.
The tree looks like this ->

```
CommunityView(Stateful Widget)
WillPopScope
ProviderScope
Consumer
Scaffold
...and so on
```

Now inside the build method of the CommunityView Widget,

```
 final params = _VSControllerParams(
      selectedFamily: widget.selectedFamily,
    );
    print('familiesStatus: rebuild main');

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: onWillPop,
      child: ProviderScope(
        overrides: [_paramsProvider.overrideWithValue(params)],
        child: Consumer(
          builder: (context, watch, child) {
            print('familiesStatus: rebuild consumer');
            final state = watch(_vsProvider(params));
            final stateController = watch(_vsProvider(params).notifier);
```

The `rebuild main` print happens only once, while the `rebuild consumer` print happens twice. Previously home page fetched data and then shows data fetched or error depending on network response. Now I use an enum to get loading state, i.e. ApiStatus.loading is the initial state, then ApiStatus.success or failure depending on response.  Now what I have changed that is causing this issue is -> I have added a function call in initstate that fetches local saved cache and loads data from that. So what happens is ApiStatus.loading->ApiStatus.success(Cache fetched)->ApiStatus.loading(somehow whole widget rebuild)->ApiStatus.success(cache fetched again)->ApiStatus.success(Data fetched from internet). So I am not sure why it is rebuilding first time when cache is fetched.

Now to fix this, I first tried to find any reason in the cache method call that is causing this rebuild, but was not able to find any even with heavy debugging. Then I thought to create a global parameter which is something like this

```
bool fetchDataFromCache = true;
```

and then inside initState, I call fetch Cache method something like this

```
if(fetchDataFromCache){
    fetchCache();
    fetchDataFromCache = false;
}
```

But this caused the ApiStatus loading parameter to change like this ->ApiStatus.loading(initial build)->ApiStatus.success(Cache fetched)->ApiStatus.loading(somehow whole widget rebuild)->ApiStatus.success(Data fetched from internet). So widget is still rebuilding because I have set ApiStatus.loading only in initState, and nowhere else. So it is still glitching out.

Demo video - https://youtu.be/1EzYfCRiwk0